# Read/write in mongo replicaSet from apache spark raises 'not master' error

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, replicaset

I have an Apache Spark program that loads data from a mongodb collection and writes to another one. Sometimes works fine but other raises the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoNotPrimaryException: Command failed with error 10107 (NotWritablePrimary): 'not master' on server mongodb-headless:27017. The full response is {"errorLabels": ["RetryableWriteError"], "topologyVersion": {"processId": {"$oid": "622f893b6311755cbcd320b8"}, "counter": 3}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1647360479, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "not master", "code": 10107, "codeName": "NotWritablePrimary", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1647360479, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}}
```

From my understanding It seems to sometimes connect to the writable master and other to the secondary read replica, raising the error.

I use the following code to read/write the dataframe:

```scala
val database = "..."
val collection = "..."
val rs = "rs0"
val uri = s"mongodb://$host:$port/$database?replicaSet=$rs"

var df = MongoSpark.load(
      spark,
      ReadConfig(Map(
        "uri" -> uri,
        "database" -> database,
        "collection" -> collection,
        "replicaSet" -> rs
        )
      ))
// ...
MongoSpark.save(
      df,
      WriteConfig(Map(
        "uri" -> uri,
        "database" -> database,
        "collection" -> collection,
        "replicaSet" -> rs
      )))
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance